# Expose flask via apache without wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask

For some purpose of testing, I do not want to use the wsgi script to expose a flask web app. So, I am running the flask application like `sudo -u  www-data python index.py` which runs the app on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`, then in my apache config, I set a proxypass  `ProxyPass "/ldpdfend" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"` but it is not working and i am getting a 404. What config is needed to route the request properly to the application via apache ? . This is the conf file where the apache config is set:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com
        ProxyPass "/ldpdfend" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"


        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain/site
        <Directory /var/www/html/domain/site>
                Require all granted
                Options all
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your apache configs, or at least the relevant sections?

Comment: Are there any files called `proxy.load` and `proxy_http.load` inside `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`?

Comment: Do you have any other ``VirtualHost`` definitions? Where did you add this one? What platform are you using? Is ``domain.com`` really what you are using? Are using that in the URL as well when making request? Likely your ``VirtualHost`` definition isn't even been used.

Comment: @xyres, yes I have `proxy.load` inside `etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, yes I have other definitions, i'm using debian based distribution, domain.com is just the placeholder for my domain, yeah when making the request, it is of the form http://example.com/ldpdfend/params and I want this to route to http://127.0.0.1:5000/params (using example instead of domain)

Comment: Does logging of Flask application show the request made it? What are the form of the routes in the Flask application? Do they include ``/ldpdfend`` in them?

Comment: no logging doesn't, i'm trying to investigate this, i believe it has more to do with apache than flask

Comment: @Noor I think you also need a `proxy_http.load` file in that directory to enable proxying. Type this command - `sudo a2enmod proxy_http` and Apache will put that file there automatically. Restart the server and see if works now.